# What happens to the fourier transform of sample result of $30kHz$ sinusoidal signal when sampled with sample frequency $44.1KHz$?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, sampling

As the title says,w hat happens to the fourier transform of the sample output of $30KHz$ when sampled with sample frequency $44.1KHz$? I do not get how alias can appear, because fourier transform of pure sinusoidal signal contains impulse, not shape...

Answer (score 2):

What happens is you get an FT result that is identical to the FT of a 14.1 kHz input.  There is no way to tell from just the FT result the correct input frequency.

Comment: You can't tell just from the FT result, but you can intentionally band pass your input signal before digitizing it.  Since you then know the range of frequencies to expect, you can interpret your FT results correctly.  So, you could band pass your signal so that it only contains frequencies from 22050 to 44100, sample at 44100, and then you would know that 14.1kHz in the FT maps to a 30Khz sinusoidal signal.